# How do I find the efficient frontier without having variance?

Tags: microeconomics

[image]

How is it possible to find the efficient frontier?
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Hi, I don't see a problem here. You have all the information you need. Probably it's confusing that you don't have the variance and mean given directly so you need to calculate that first. Start with the mean,  then variance. As the second asset is a risk free asset try to remember what the correlation here is. Good luck

Comment: Thank you for your reply T123. No problem in computing the mean but I get issues when computing the standard deviation because I get a square root of a fraction… would you be available to give me some further help? Please 

Comment: Would you mind showing what you got so far?